# Javascript : Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, model-view-controller, yii

I've got this error message :

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('hidden') does not support selection.

When I check the console, it says error in this code:

```
function simpan() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'app/tblhasilsurvey/simpan',
        type: 'post',
        async: false,
        data: {
            cmd: window.cmd,
            id: window.id_hasilsurvey,
            id_daftar: window.id_daftar,
            id_jadwal: window.id_jadwal,
            //tblhasilsurvey_nobasurvey : $("#nomor_ba_survey").val(),
            nomor_izin : $("#nomor_izin").val(),
            tgl_izin : $("#tgl_izin").val(),
            pemilik_izin : $("#pemilik_izin").val(),
            lokasi : $("#lokasi").val(),
            kodekel : $("#kelurahan").val(),
            kodekec : $("#kecamatan").val(),
            tblhasilsurvey_tglbasurvey : $("#tgl_ba_survey").val(),
            tbldaftarrencanasurvey_koordinat : $("#lattitude_").val()+';'+$("#longitude_").val(), // (lattitude;longitude)
            tblhasilsurvey_fungsibangunan : $("#fungsi_bangunan").val(),
            tblhasilsurvey_uraianpermasalahan : $("#uraian_permasalahan").val(),
            tblizin_id : $("#tblizin_id").val()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if(data=='success') {
                notifikasi('Sukses','Data Berhasil Disimpan', 'success');
                //window.location.reload();
            } else {
                notifikasi('Gagal','Data Gagal Disimpan', 'fail');
            }
        }
    });
    if( $("#lattitude_").val() !='' ) window.pos_lat = $("#lattitude_").val(); // jika koordinat terisi maka update posisi lattitude
    if( $("#longitude_").val() !='' ) window.pos_long = $("#longitude_").val(); // jika koordinat terisi maka update posisi longitude

    $("#peta-lokasi").slideDown(1000);
    initialize();
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 2500);
    return false;

    function refresh () {
        window.location.reload();
    }
}
```

Can someone explain me what happen here?

Comment: Which specific line has the error? Is there a stack trace? The error seems self explanatory; something (maybe not in this code, but in something it calls like `notifikasi` or `initialize`) is probably trying to read `selectionDirection` on a hidden element.

Answer (score 14):

Somewhere in your HTML you have an `<input type='hidden' />` which you are trying to add to your data obj, but you are probably adding the jQuery object and this message is likely getting thrown when the jQuery object is being stringified somewhere. Given most of your data object is built by explicitly calling `.val()` I'd guess the problem lies with one of these:

```
        cmd: window.cmd,
        id: window.id_hasilsurvey,
        id_daftar: window.id_daftar,
        id_jadwal: window.id_jadwal,
```

try commenting those out and see if your error goes away. If it does, then the problem can probably be solved by adding `.val()` to the end of the problematic line.

---

**EDIT AND EXTENSION**

(Apr 9, 2015) This answer has had 3 upvotes since I wrote it, all spread out in time, so I guess other people are hitting this error and finding this answer, so here is a more general explanation to help people out.

This error is thrown if you add the jQuery object representing a hidden input to a JS object, then try to serialise that JS object to JSON.

Demo reproducing the error in its simplest form:

http://jsfiddle.net/ptugva6t/2/

Using this HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="test1" value="test1_val" />
```

Then `#test1` will trigger the error if we use this JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = {
        test1: $("#test1")
    }
    JSON.stringify(data)
});
```

whereas this will be OK:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = {
        test1: $("#test1").val()
    }
    JSON.stringify(data)
});
```

Whereas if you use a text input you won't hit this error, but you will likely hit other serialisation errors due to the complexity of the object you are trying to serialise!

---

**UPDATE**

(7 September 2016) It looks like this was only ever a Chrome bug and it has been fixed in a recent Chrome update. There is now no error at all in Chrome 52 and you can JSON.stringify a jquery object with no problem.

Firefox is also OK. Safari 9.1.1 still throws an error, though - a TypeError on JSON.stringify that can be fixed by adding the .val()

So there's a mini-project arising, to find the Chrome bug report and its fix, and report it to Safari.

Comment: It's a very user unfriendly error message! This really helped to clarify my issue.

Comment: Apparently something has changed, because when I try the provided fiddle it does not trigger an error, regardless of whether or not I append .val() to the jQuery call.

Comment: That's really interesting, thanks for mentioning that. I created a fiddle that prints to the console the result of serialising the jquery object. You're right, it does work fine and produces reasonably sane output: http://jsfiddle.net/ptugva6t/16/ I'll see if I can figure out what changed.

Comment: I tried with some old version of jquery to see if I could reproduce the problem; ie, is the fault in the jquery object itself? but no, it still worked fine. So I think this must have been fixed in the latest version of Chrome, with an improvement to JSON.stringify. If you run the fiddle in Safari, you still get a problem 'TypeError', which can be fixed with the .val() ... I'll update the answer.