# Ajax Insert value null in database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

When I alert all field values, they look perfect, but when I try to insert into DB using PHP, all values are `null`. What's happening?

Here is my HTML

```
<form action="ajax.php" id="myform" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="userid" name="userid" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" />
  <input type="hidden" id="courseid" name="courseid" value="1" />
  <li class="active">
    <div id="#mybox">
      <a class="" id="media-play1" state="1"><i class="fa fa-play-circle-o"></i> Welcome <p>55s</p></a>
    </div>
  </li>
</form>
```

JQuery Ajax

```
$("#media-play1").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
        var userid = $("#userid").val();
        var courseid = $("#courseid").val();
        var coursename = $("#coursename").text();
        alert(userid);
        alert(courseid);
        alert(coursename);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        async: true,
        cache: true,
        data: alert("userid=" + userid + "&courseid=" + courseid + "&coursename=" + coursename),
        type: 'POST',           
        //data:alert($(this).serialize()),
        success: function(){alert('success');},
        //dataType: "json",
    }); });
```

My PHP file

```
session_start();
include_once('admin/conn.php');
if(isset($_POST['userid'])){
echo $userid = $_POST['userid'];
echo $courseid = $_POST['courseid'];
echo $coursename = $_POST['coursename'];

$queryin = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tranings` (`id`, `userid`, `courseid`, `traninigname`) VALUES ('','".$userid."','".$courseid."','".$coursename."')") or die(mysql_error());

if($queryin){
  echo 'insert';
} else {
  echo 'not insert';
}
```

Comment: You don't have an id called "coursename" nor a named attribute of the same.

Comment: what should `data: alert(...)` in `$.ajax({`do ?

Comment: i cant understand what mean by id call coursename?

Comment: First of all: when invoking the PHP script without ajax, does it work? Second: it seems to me you have extra "echo"s in your PHP code.

Comment: `#coursename` <= for that. You do have `id="courseid"` etc. but not for coursename.

Comment: show all data when i alert

Comment: here is that `<h2 id="coursename">Turbo Twitter - How To Rapidly Build Your First 10,000 Fans </h2>` that is top of the form its my course heading

Comment: yes its work without ajax and php script are perfect insert all null values its means insert query work fine but not get tha values

Comment: Your table name `tranings` are you sure you didn't mean `trainings`? MySQL should be throwing an error if that is the case. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. See if MySQL is sending you errors or not.

Comment: use this `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` no error found insert null data  :(

Answer (score 1):

Please alter your `Ajax` call like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        async: true,
        cache: true,
        data: "userid=" + userid + "&courseid=" + courseid + "&coursename=" + coursename,
        type: 'POST',           
        //data:alert($(this).serialize()),
        success: function(){alert('success');},
        //dataType: "json",
    });
```

you are using alert in Data. 
In addition to this I would like to suggest use `serialize` method its much better option here is the example: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0):

First of all as mentioned in the comments for you question the `$("#coursename")` element is not in the html you provided, so `var coursename = $("#coursename").text();` equals nothing.

As for the issue as to why your data is not being passed to your php you are passing a call to `alert()` as your data attribute in you ajax call when it should be a function that returns data or an object like so

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'ajax.php',
        async: true,
        cache: true,
        data: {
             userid: userid,
             courseid: courseid,
             coursename: coursename
        },
        type: 'POST',           
        //data:alert($(this).serialize()),
        success: function(data){
             console.log(data); // log the returned data
             alert('success');
        },
        //dataType: "json",
    });
```

Comment: Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to read the 'selectionDirection' property from 'HTMLInputElement': The input element's type ('hidden') does not support selection

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27659465/1520678) for the issue you have now having, its basically because you are passing the jQuery object in the data object rather than the value string